# Dokuwiki Bootstrap3 Page Width

Tags: css, wiki, dokuwiki

Sorry, Doku/CSS newbie here. I am just wondering how I can change the width of the Wiki of the main page? See - https://littlesimworld.com/. The default bootstrap3 will always fill the screen.

Is there a way of giving a maximum allowed width? This is important because simply setting a fixed width is bad for mobile and mode. It needs to be set to fill the screen until a certain width is reached. When that width is reached it should stop expanding. This issue happens when viewing on ultrawide mode. In addition, the above navigation bar also needs to match the width of the page. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Go into configuration in admin and turn on fluidcontainers.